# Call contract and send value from Solidity

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-invocation

I have a pre-deployed `contractA` with known ABI. I would like to call function `func1(string,string)` in the `contractA` (and pass the arguments) from a new `contractB` and send some value at the same time. So far, I managed to write the following  (which does not send the arguments properly):

```
    contract contractB is mortal  {
        function invokeContractA() { 
            address contractAaddress= 0x1234567891234567891234567891234567891234;
            uint ValueToSend = 1234;
            contractAaddress.call.value(ValueToSend)(bytes4(sha3("func1(string,string)")),
                 "arg1TEXT", "arg2TEXT");
        }  
    }
```

Would appreciate your suggestions on what else is missing here (perhaps, need to convert the arguments into bytecode somehow?).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here's an approach that's simpler and checked by the compiler:

```
contract contractA {
    function blah(int x, int y) payable {}
}

contract contractB {
    function invokeContractA() { 
        contractA a = contractA(0x1234567891234567891234567891234567891234);
        uint ValueToSend = 1234;
        a.blah{value: ValueToSend}(2, 3);
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thank you. What if I do not know the code of contractA, just the ABI?

Comment: You don't need to know all the code, just the signatures of the functions you want to call. Put those in your contractA definition like I did there, and you're good. Really you're just defining an interface.

Comment: If you don't know the code of ContractA, you can call the function directly using ```.call``` . See [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9733/calling-function-from-deployed-contract/9735) for more detail.

Answer (score 6):

A more modern style, as the last answer has gone a bit out of date:

```
(tokenInAfterFee, tokenOutAmt) = spclContract.swap{value: msg.value}(_spctToSwap);
```

*(edit: the accepted answer was edited after I posted this to match mine. Not sure that's a good idea, it's good to have access to old code as well... Anyways...)*