# How to specify gas/value when making a call using abstract contracts?

Tags: contract-invocation

How does one specify gas or value making a call this way:

```
contract AbstractB {
    function getX() returns(uint);
}

contract A {
    function makeCall(address addressB){
         AbstractB(addressB).getX();
    }
}
```

---

The following doesn't work(**Error: Member "gas" not found...**):

```
AbstractB(addressB).gas(0).getX();
```

Comment: Related: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6665/call-contract-and-send-value-from-solidity

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDIT: I upvoted and recommend @Xavier's answer (@BokkyPooBah's answer is missing `()` at the end).

It's more type-safe and here's an example showing the return value of `getX`.  You do need to provide non-zero gas:

```
contract AbstractB {
    function getX() returns(uint) {
        return 3;
    }
}

contract A {
    function makeCall(address addressB) returns(uint) {
        return AbstractB(addressB).getX.gas(1000)();
    }
}
```

**OLD:** Use `call.gas(g).value(v)(methodId, args)` syntax. **Not recommended** because not type-safe and you don't get the return value of `getX`.

Example: `addressB.call.gas(0).value(1 ether)(bytes4(sha3("getX()")));`

Complete example, which should always checks the return value of `call`:

```
contract AbstractB {
    function getX() returns(uint);
}

contract A {
    function makeCall(address addressB){
         if (!addressB.call.gas(0).value(1 ether)(bytes4(sha3("getX()")))) {
             throw;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, good sir!!! I guess, it also means that there's no point in having `AbstractB` contract at all there?

Comment: Yes, but actually the other answers that use `AbstractB` are safer for type-safety.

Answer (score 4):

`AbstractB(addressB).getX.gas(0)();`

Notice the many parentheses: `(0)()`

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
contract AbstractB {
    function getX() returns(uint);
}

contract A {
    function makeCall(address addressB) {
        AbstractB(addressB).getX.value(1 ether).gas(0);
    }
}
```

EDIT: As noted by the other answers to this question, the code `AbstractB(addressB).getX.value(1 ether).gas(0);` above is incorrect and should be replaced by:

```
        AbstractB(addressB).getX.value(1 ether).gas(0)();
```

Answer (score 1):

I've compiled these two contracts using solidity online compiler. I've changed only one line.

- `AbstractB(addressB).getX.gas(0);` @BokkyPooBah solution
- `AbstractB(addressB).getX.gas(0)();` @xavier-leprêtre solution

And got massively different **bytecodes**:

6060604052601e8060106000396000f3606060405260e060020a60003504637ff76d728114601a575b005b601856

**vs**

606060405260848060106000396000f3606060405260e060020a60003504637ff76d728114601a575b005b60186004357f5197c7aa00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000606090815273ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff821690635197c7aa906000906064906020906004818588803b1560025787f115600257505050505056

---

```
contract AbstractB {
    function getX() returns(uint);
}

contract A {
    function makeCall(address addressB){
         AbstractB(addressB).getX.gas(0);
    }
}
```

---

```
contract AbstractB {
    function getX() returns(uint);
}

contract A {
    function makeCall(address addressB){
         AbstractB(addressB).getX.gas(0)();
    }
}
```

I don't mind the difference in bytecode size, what's scary is that these contracts might have some behaviour differences. What's going on there?

Comment: The extra `()` is needed to make the actual call and obtain return a value.  (Example in my edited answer.)