# Error: Member "value" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in function

Tags: solidity

Using the online Solidity compiler **I get this error:**

```
browser/TokenSales.sol:18:10: Error: Member "value" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in function (address) external returns (bool) - did you forget the "payable" modifier?
    if (!TokenSalesInterface(tokenSales).proxyPurchase.value(msg.value).gas(106000)(payout)) throw;
         ^-------------------------------------------------^
```

**For this code:**

```
contract ProxyPayment {

  address payout;
  address tokenSales; 
  address owner;

  function ProxyPayment(address _payout, address _tokenSales) {
    payout = _payout;
    tokenSales = _tokenSales;
    owner = _payout;
  }

  function () {
    if (!TokenSalesInterface(tokenSales).proxyPurchase.value(msg.value).gas(106000)(payout)) throw;
  }

}
```

This is my [repo](https://github.com/drhouse7/solidity).

**How can I fix this issue?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You  can fix it by whether downgrading the used compiler to a version prior to 0.4.0 or using the following call :

```
 if (!TokenSalesInterface(tokenSales).call.gas(106000).value(msg.value)(bytes4(sha3("proxyPurchase(address)")),payout)) {
             throw;
         }
```

if you are using a recent compiler don't forget to use `payable` in the functions which receive ethers.
related post : [How to specify gas/value when making a call using abstract contracts?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8201/how-to-specify-gas-value-when-making-a-call-using-abstract-contracts)

Comment: Why should you downgrade the compiler version. The code should be modified to match the latest once since not many changes would be required and great features are provides(especially after 0.4.0=9)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access msg.value in

```
function () {
  if (!TokenSalesInterface(tokenSales).proxyPurchase.value(msg.value).gas(106000)(payout)) throw;
}
```

but the fallback function is not defined as payable, so it cannot take ether.

Also the function

```
function proxyPurchase(address _user) returns (bool success) {
  return purchase(_user, msg.value);
}
```

Takes address as an input and returns boolean value while you are passing uint value as msg.value.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
  function () payable { 
    if (!TokenSalesInterface(tokenSales).proxyPurchase(msg.sender)) throw;
  }
```

The function `proxyPurchase` requires one argument:

```
  function proxyPurchase(address _user) returns (bool success) {
    return purchase(_user, msg.value);
  }
```