# What happens when you use multiple "call" arguments?

Tags: solidity, evm, eth-call

I have a piece of code like so:

```
address x=0x01234..;
x.call(data1, data2, data3);
```

Will this do what I expect and call the contract at address `x` while passing the data in concatenated like data1+data2+data3 (and bare, without any solidity ABI formatting)? I can't find any documentation about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The low-level `.call` function allows you to call a function by its function signature calculated as `bytes4(sha3("functionName()"))`. Also take a look at https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/9722/16 and [Call contract and send value from Solidity](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/6665/16). If your function has parameters, the signature looks as follows `bytes4(sha3("functionName(uint256,string,address)"))` - keep in mind that instead of `uint` you have to use `uint256`. The following parameters are the actual values of the parameters. Thus, the whole call would look like

```
x.call(bytes4(sha3("functionName(uint256,string,address)")), myUIntVal, myStringVal, myAddressVal);
```

You can also specify a specific gas or value (ether (but in Wei!) to send along) like this:

```
x.call.value(1234)(bytes4(sha3("functionName(uint256,string,address)")), myUIntVal, myStringVal, myAddressVal);
```

Comment: Cool, that matches what I was thinking it did, but couldn't find any documentation confirming it or even indicating that `call` can take multiple arguments

Comment: IMO most documentation is still patchy. Please do help other people here or on sites where you find some info missing and would expect it.